# The rectangle created by a Chart Range Filter Control is much bigger than the control

Tags: google-visualization

I am using the React Google charts. I created a line chart and wanted to put some control below it to zoom and pan the chart.

I set the `height` of the `chartArea` as 25% of the chart which is 300px.

However, the control create a big white rectangle around it that is 200px of height so it is much too big in comparison to the height of the controls.

I would like to know how I could fix this please. I tried to put a cssClass setting `height=100px` in too places of the controls but it didn't work. I don't see the class anywhere in the html code. Thank you

As you can see there is a big white space below the controls https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMJvS.jpg

```
{
return (
  <div className="App">
  <Chart
  width={'100%'}
  height={'300px'}
  chartType="ComboChart"
  loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
  data={[["Time","Count", "Accumulate"],...this.props.data.normal]}

  options={{
    title: this.props.title,
    chartArea: { width: '80%'},
    // left:0,top:10
    hAxis: {
        format: 'M/d/yy',
        title: 'Time'
    },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {1: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex: 1}},
    explorer: { 
        actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
        maxZoomIn: 8.0
    },
    vAxes: { 0: { title: 'Medias', minValue: 0}, 1: {title: 'Accumulate', minValue: 0} }​,
    }}
    controls={[
        {
            controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
            options: {
                filterColumnIndex: 0,
                ui: {
                    chartType: 'LineChart',
                    chartOptions: {
                        chartArea: { width: '90%', height: '25%' },
                        hAxis: { baselineColor: 'none' },
                    },
                },
            },
            controlPosition: 'bottom',
            controlWrapperParams: {
                state: {
                    range: { start: new Date(2017, 1, 9), end: new Date(2018, 12, 20) },
                },
            },
        },
    ]}
  rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
/>
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53725130/5090771), you can use option `chartArea` on both the chart and filter...

Comment: bubulledu93, did you ever find an answer to this? chartArea does not seem to be solving the problem.