# Why does the chartArea configuration option hide hAxis ticks?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm a beginner in the Apps Script environment.
While testing to learn about methods and configuration options, I came across a problem for which I couldn't find a solution.
After changing the chartArea option, depending on the value, the hAxis ticks disappear.
As an example taken directly from the google guide [page](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart), I have this snippet:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes);

function drawCurveTypes() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');

      data.addRows([
        [0, 0, 0],    [1, 10, 5],   [2, 23, 15],  [3, 17, 9],   [4, 18, 10],  [5, 9, 5],
        [6, 11, 3],   [7, 27, 19],  [8, 33, 25],  [9, 40, 32],  [10, 32, 24], [11, 35, 27],
        [12, 30, 22], [13, 40, 32], [14, 42, 34], [15, 47, 39], [16, 44, 36], [17, 48, 40],
        [18, 52, 44], [19, 54, 46], [20, 42, 34], [21, 55, 47], [22, 56, 48], [23, 57, 49],
        [24, 60, 52], [25, 50, 42], [26, 52, 44], [27, 51, 43], [28, 49, 41], [29, 53, 45],
        [30, 55, 47], [31, 60, 52], [32, 61, 53], [33, 59, 51], [34, 62, 54], [35, 65, 57],
        [36, 62, 54], [37, 58, 50], [38, 55, 47], [39, 61, 53], [40, 64, 56], [41, 65, 57],
        [42, 63, 55], [43, 66, 58], [44, 67, 59], [45, 69, 61], [46, 69, 61], [47, 70, 62],
        [48, 72, 64], [49, 68, 60], [50, 66, 58], [51, 65, 57], [52, 67, 59], [53, 70, 62],
        [54, 71, 63], [55, 72, 64], [56, 73, 65], [57, 75, 67], [58, 70, 62], [59, 68, 60],
        [60, 64, 56], [61, 60, 52], [62, 65, 57], [63, 67, 59], [64, 68, 60], [65, 69, 61],
        [66, 70, 62], [67, 72, 64], [68, 75, 67], [69, 80, 72]
      ]);

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Popularity'
        },
        series: {
          1: {curveType: 'function'}
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

If I modify the given example, including the following configuration: `chartArea: {left: 70, width:'90%', height:'90%'}`, the hAxis ticks just disappear, as we can see in the next snippet.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes);

function drawCurveTypes() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');

      data.addRows([
        [0, 0, 0],    [1, 10, 5],   [2, 23, 15],  [3, 17, 9],   [4, 18, 10],  [5, 9, 5],
        [6, 11, 3],   [7, 27, 19],  [8, 33, 25],  [9, 40, 32],  [10, 32, 24], [11, 35, 27],
        [12, 30, 22], [13, 40, 32], [14, 42, 34], [15, 47, 39], [16, 44, 36], [17, 48, 40],
        [18, 52, 44], [19, 54, 46], [20, 42, 34], [21, 55, 47], [22, 56, 48], [23, 57, 49],
        [24, 60, 52], [25, 50, 42], [26, 52, 44], [27, 51, 43], [28, 49, 41], [29, 53, 45],
        [30, 55, 47], [31, 60, 52], [32, 61, 53], [33, 59, 51], [34, 62, 54], [35, 65, 57],
        [36, 62, 54], [37, 58, 50], [38, 55, 47], [39, 61, 53], [40, 64, 56], [41, 65, 57],
        [42, 63, 55], [43, 66, 58], [44, 67, 59], [45, 69, 61], [46, 69, 61], [47, 70, 62],
        [48, 72, 64], [49, 68, 60], [50, 66, 58], [51, 65, 57], [52, 67, 59], [53, 70, 62],
        [54, 71, 63], [55, 72, 64], [56, 73, 65], [57, 75, 67], [58, 70, 62], [59, 68, 60],
        [60, 64, 56], [61, 60, 52], [62, 65, 57], [63, 67, 59], [64, 68, 60], [65, 69, 61],
        [66, 70, 62], [67, 72, 64], [68, 75, 67], [69, 80, 72]
      ]);

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        chartArea: {left: 70, width:'90%', height:'90%'},
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Popularity'
        },
        series: {
          1: {curveType: 'function'}
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Depending on the value of the height parameter, the ticks appear again and I couldn't understand why increasing the graph area implies omitting the hAxis ticks.
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53725130/5090771)...

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat.
I believe the version used in this answer is not the same as the chartArea.botton parameter no longer appears in the documentation.

Comment: But anyway, it helped me as it has a snippet of code on how to resize the graph after changing the browser window, which I was looking for.

Comment: `chartArea.bottom` was never in the documentation. the option was added with [version # 43 on october 2, 2015](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#october-2,-2015)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `chartArea.height` = 200

Default `height` = `chartArea.height` = 200

`chartArea.height: 90%` -> 180

200- 180 = 20px is not enough for the `hAxis` that it is out of the display region.

You should reduce `chartArea.height` or increase `height`.

Comment: Thanks @idfurw.
Is the default chartArea.height really 200 or was it just an example?

Comment: Actually, an example. I cannot find it on document by it is the value when I run you snippet.